# Автоматический ввод команд в терминале Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, скрипт, терминал

Есть ли возможность написать скрипт или что-то наподобие этого, который будет построчно считывать команды из txt-файла и вводить их поочерёдно в терминал?

Comment: Обязательно из txt? Может быть просто использовать обычный bash скрипт? В нем также будут выполняться команды построчно

Comment: Не обязательно txt

Comment: без уточнения, что именно подразумевается под словом «вводить» вопрос не имеет никакого смысла.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
touch any_name.txt
```

Далее заполняем any_name.txt своими командами с помощью любимого редактора. Далее запускаем его как скрипт.

```
bash any_name.txt
```

Собственно все...
p.s. файл может называться как угодно.

---

**UPD** с поправкой на комментарии:

```
while read -r line 
    do
         if [[ "$line" ]]; then 
             echo "$line"
             sleep 3
             if bash -c "$line"; then
                 echo "${line}: Done"
             else
                 echo "${line}: Fail"
             fi
         fi
         sleep 3
done < any_name.txt
```

---

Еще один вариант из коментов. Спасибо, @Hellseher.

```
< any_name.txt xargs -I% bash -c "echo '%';sleep 3;%;sleep 3"
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно сделать так, чтобы команда сначала печаталась в терминале, а только потом выполнялась?

Comment: Всмысле вам нужно что-бы она просто выводилась в терминал или для каждой команды выводился запрос подтверждения на выполнение?

Comment: `while read -r line; do echo "$line";sleep 3;bash -c "$line";sleep 3;done<any_name.txt` попробуйте запустить. Это то что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: Да, это то, что нужно, только после выполнения 2 команд он прекращает работу. При необходимости могу отправить скриншот или список всех команд.

Comment: Да содержимое файла подойдет гораздо лучше

Comment: @Fisherman в вашу копилку  `~$ < text_file xargs -I% printf "%\n"` чтение построчно. Если кончено  cat/awk/grep/sed не в милость :)  `~$ list_of_commands xargs -I% sh -c "sleep 1; %"`

Comment: И таки да. На этот раз Вы правы. Ваш вариант элегантней. Век живи - век учись. (Все равно дураком помрешь)

Answer (score 2):

Скажем так, если вы можете просто написать скрипт полагаясь на нижеуказанную статью.

[Основы Bash](https://habr.com/post/47163/)

Если вы хотите выполнять построчно один скрипт из другого скрипта, это уже посложнее будет. Но в целом данная серия статей вам поможет это сделать.